# loading big .npy file causing python to stop working

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, io

I am trying to load a .npy file which is quite big (6GB) and I get a `Python has stopped working` error. Any suggestions as to how to approach getting around this issue? [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use buffering for bigger files eg:

```
with open("bigfile.npy","r",buffering=1000) as f:
    contents=f.read()
    #do something with the fist n lines of file at a time
```

this willn't open the entire file altogether but instead only the quantity that you specify as integer in buffering arg (you can decide on what you want depending on the system you are working on) and the system will not stop working.